# How to print byte array in shell

Tags: shell, sh

I want to print the below array in shell

```
#!/bin/bash
export val={ 'A','P','I','R'}
```

Error

> line 5: export: `A,P,I,R}': not a valid identifier

Comment: The code you posted, is invalid. That is not an array. The error you are getting is a result of invalid syntax. There is no "bytes" array in shell - in shell, everything is a string. What exactly do you want to print? What is the input? You can learn about Bash arrays online.

Comment: I want to save this { 'A','P','I','R'} array in my local machine and make use of it in my programming by exporting it.

Comment: You should start by giving the [bash manual section on arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) a good read.

Comment: Arrays cannot be exported. The values of environment variables are simple strings. You might use `export val="A,P,I,R"` and then the process that consumes this value would have to split the string on commas to create an array.